# Way to express generic from conversions on custom type in Rust?

Tags: rust, types, traits

I have this type with some from trait implementations:

```rust
struct BEEData {
    data: Vec<u8>
}

impl From<u8> for BEEData {
    fn from(data: u8) -> BEEData {
        BEEData{data: vec![data]}
    }
}
```

For now I only have `u8`, but I expect to end up with more, such as `u16,` u32`or a plain`Vec`.

How can I write a wrapper function using `from` inside in a way that I do not need to repeat it for each implementator type of the `from` conversion?

I mean given this:

```rust
impl BEEData {
...
    fn wrap(slice: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<BEEData> {
        let mut bee_data = vec![];
        for i in slice {
            bee_data.push(BEEData::from(i));
        }
        bee_data
    }
}
```

When I try to replace `u8` by `T` I enter a debate with the compiler that I do not know how to win.

Because I do not know how to express that `T` should be *"any type as long as `BEEData` implements `From<T>`"*.

Comment: `where BEEData: From<T>` or `T: Into<BEEData>`

Comment: `T: Into<BEEData>`. `Into<U> for T` is automatically implemented where `U: From<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your requirement as a `where` clause:

```
impl BEEData {
    fn wrap<T>(slice: Vec<T>) -> Vec<BEEData>
    where
        BEEData: From<T>,
    {
        let mut bee_data = vec![];
        for i in slice {
            bee_data.push(BEEData::from(i));
        }
        bee_data
    }
}
```

This just means that the function is valid for any choice of `T`, as long as `BEEData` implements `From<T>`.

You could also write it the other way around, since `Into<BEEData>` is automatically implemented for `T` if `From<T>` is implemented for `BEEData`:

```
impl BEEData {
    fn wrap<T>(slice: Vec<T>) -> Vec<BEEData>
    where
        T: Into<BEEData>,
    {
        let mut bee_data = vec![];
        for i in slice {
            bee_data.push(i.into());
        }
        bee_data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works great!

I was understanding the compiler wanted the where clause at the "impl" level, which of course was not working and the "impl" block is NOT T parameterized.